# To update dash data table with a button

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I need Help!!!
I have made an entry form where you have to enter daily bases work done.
And I have a dash data table already having data of daily bases work to be done by an employee.
Once the work done by the employee is finished he or she will enter the data in the entry form and my data table will predict the next date of the work to be done.
The predicting part is working perfectly.
The only thing is as I add an entry from data it should get simultaneously updated in my dash table through any means.
As of now, I can only think of a button through which the dash table should get updated.
Open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to write a callback to have the table update based on input form value changes. This example can be adapted to generate a table ([Dash basic callback help](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks))

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='my-div')
])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'You\'ve entered "{}"'.format(input_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```